# not a class or namespace error

Tags: c++, oop

I'm struggling with an error that I haven't been able to find the solution for. I can't seem to understand why "Location" is not found as a class. here is me header file:

```
#ifndef CLASS2_HPP
#define CLASS2_HPP

class Passenger
{

public:

    enum class Location
    {
        Business,
        Economy,
        Vip
    };

    Passenger(Location clas_s, char* firstName, char* secondName, int seat, int terminal, float time_of_departure);

    const char* get_location() const;
    int get_seat() const;
    int get_terminal() const;
    float get_time() const;
    char* get_firstName() const;
    char* get_secondName() const;
    void print() const;

private:

    Location _clas_s;
    char _firstName;
    char _secondName;
    int _seat;
    int _terminal;
    float _time_of_departure;

};


#endif // CLASS2
```

And here is my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class2.hpp"

using namespace std;


Passenger::Passenger(Location clas_s, char* firstName, char* secondName, int seat, int terminal, float time_of_departure)
: _clas_s(clas_s), _firstName(firstName), _secondName(secondName), _seat(seat), _terminal(terminal), _time_of_departure(time_of_departure) {};

void Passenger::print() const
{
    cout << "Your name is " << _firstName
    << " " << _secondName << endl
    << "Your class is " << get_location() << endl
    << "Your seat is " << _seat << endl
    << "Your terminal is " << _terminal << endl
    << "Your time of departure is " << _time_of_departure << endl;
}

const char* Passenger::get_location() const
{
    switch (_clas_s)
    {
        case Location::Business : return "Business";
        case Location::Economy : return "Economy";
        case Location::Vip : return "Vip";
    }
}

int main() {

    Passenger p((Passenger::Location::Vip), 'John', 'Johnson', 25, 2, 13.53);
    p.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just on top of my head: you probably want to use Passenger::Location

Comment: On what line do you get an error?

Comment: The lines are 24/25/26/32

Comment: _"I can't seem to understand why "Location" is not found as a class."_ Probably because it's not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are on C++03, so make

```
enum Location
{
    Business,
    Economy,
    Vip
};
```

And

```
case Business : return "Business";
case Economy : return "Economy";
case Vip : return "Vip";
```

**Edit:** I was wrong about

> You forgot to set Passenger::Passenger(**Passenger::** Location
>   clas_s,...

Comment: @RostislavGeorgiev and make     `char * _firstName; char * _secondName;`

Comment: It still doesn't work but thanks I'll keep on trying to fix it

Comment: Not necessary: the constructor parameters are looked up in the scope of the class.

Comment: Yes thank you very much do you know what was causing the problem

Comment: @RostislavGeorgiev what is you compiler? if it is a gcc and modern, compile with -std=c++11 command line option. C++03 standard has no strong typed enum class.

Comment: Aha ok yes it was the complier giving me problems. Well thank you very much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `Passenger` you have to pass strings using the double quotes, not single quotes (which are for single characters only):

```
Passenger p((Passenger::Location::Vip), "John", "Johnson", 25, 2, 13.53);
```

Then, you have declared `_firstName` and `_secondName` as `char`. But this would only let you store a single character! A simple solution is to use an array (but it would be much better to use the appropriate structure, which is a `std::string`, so that you don't need to worry about the size):

```
char _firstName[50];
char _secondName[50];
```

Then, to initialize them you need to `#include <cstring>` and, in the constrcutor's body (not in the initializer list!)

```
strcpy(_firstName, firstName);
strcpy(_secondName, secondName);
```

(Again, a `std::string` would be better, you could set it in the initializer list)

With these changes it compiles and the output, as expected, is:

> Your name is John Johnson
>   Your class is Vip
>   Your seat is 25
>   Your terminal is 2
>   Your time of departure is 13.53

Tested on [ideone](http://ideone.com/tqEcfb).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error:

```
Class.cpp:24:14: warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        case Location::Business : return "Business";
```

As it states, its a C++11 feature, so try compiling your code with "-std=c++11" option. Or change the switch case with integer values:

```
   switch (_clas_s)
    {
        case 0: return "Business";
        case 1: return "Economy";
        case 2: return "Vip";
    }
```

Hope that helps.